# SQL Server connection error using name instance

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows-firewall

I am using an SQL Server named instance, and I used the [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) URI format,

jdbc:sqlserver://EC2AMAZ-LKTS\MSSQLSERVER:1433;encrypt=false;

in simple Java code, but it returns the below error.

Format: sqlserver://\:1433;encrypt=false;

I have verified TCP/IP is enabled on my end and port 1433 is configured under IPVII.
I verified 1433 port inbound and outbound rules, and they seem to be good.

Why I am getting this error?

> The TCP/IP connection to the host EC2AMAZ-LKTS, port 1433 has failed. Error:
> "EC2AMAZ-LKTS. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of
> SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at
> the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked
> by a firewall

Comment: Combining named instance and port means you haven't read the docs and are not doing things correctly, it's either or. I prefer to avoid instance names altogether and just do the port thing

Comment: Agreed. Either use a static port number and not the instance name, or use the name (but then you need to make sure SQL Browser service is started and has a firewall exception).

Comment: Tried a couple of combinations, not working example : jdbc:sqlserver://EC2AMAZ-LKTS:1433;encrypt=false; . the requirement was I need to include the instance name in the JDBC URI , seems my instance name and hostname are correct.

Comment: with IP(sqlserver://10.13.81.69:1433;encrypt=false), it works, when I am trying to use the named instance, it returns the error.

Comment: for named instances, you need to have SQL Server Browser service running on target machine and port 1434 to be open through firewall. Then the server part should be EC2AMAZ-LKTS\MSSQLSERVER without port. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I tried with this URL : sqlserver://;serverName=EC2AMAZ-LKTS\SQLSERVER2024 sqlserver connected with the virtual machine, not working outside the machine. what is the issue?

Comment: What is "IPVII"? Do you mean [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) ("IPVIV") or [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) ("IPVVI")? Or something else?

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you are encountering an issue with your SQLServer named instance and the JDBC URI in your Java code. Firstly, ensure that your JDBC URI format is correct; it should be in the format "jdbc:sqlserver://:1433;encrypt=false;". Double-check the InstanceName and make sure it matches the actual name of your SQL server instance. Additionally, confirm that TCP/IP is enabled and that port 1433 is correctly configured under IPVII. Since you've already verified inbound and outbound rules for port 1433, consider checking for any firewall or security group settings on your EC2 instance that might be affecting the connection. Additionally, review SQL Server logs for any specific error messages that could provide more insight into the issue. If the problem persists, you may want to consult the SQL Server documentation or seek assistance from relevant forums for further troubleshooting.

Comment: I can connect within the virtual machine, not outside the machine. I have verified all the setup seems good. but still facing this issue "The TCP/IP connection to the host EC2AMAZ-LKTS, port 1433 has failed. Error: "No such host is known (EC2AMAZ-LKTS).

Comment: Issue is resolved using this URI : jdbc:sqlserver://testdata.org:1433\MSSQLSERVER;encrypt=false;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: What kind of [AI system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) did you use to generate this answer?